# The error boundary in react is not catching the error thrown by the child

Tags: reactjs, react-error-boundary

I have a ChatPage component as follows:

```
import React from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
import ErrorBoundary from './ErrorBoundary'
const ChatPage = () => {
  const fetchChats= async()=>{
      const data=await axios.get('/api/getChats')
      return data
  }
  
  const [chats, setChats]=React.useState(null)
  React.useEffect(()=>{
    fetchChats().then((res)=>{
     setChats(res.data)
    })
  ;
  },[])
  return (
    <>
    <div>ChatPage</div>
    <ErrorBoundary> <div>{chats.chat}</div></ErrorBoundary>
   
    </>
  )
}

export default ChatPage
```

And ErrorBoundary component as follows:

```
import React from 'react'
class ErrorBoundary extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = { hasError: false };
    }
  
    static getDerivedStateFromError(error) {
      // Update state so the next render will show the fallback UI.
      return { hasError: true };
    }
  
    componentDidCatch(error, errorInfo) {
      // You can also log the error to an error reporting service
    
    }
  
    render() {
      if (this.state.hasError) {
        // You can render any custom fallback UI
        return <h1>Something went wrong.</h1>;
      }
  
      return this.props.children; 
    }
  }
  export default ErrorBoundary
```

However, If the chats state is null, then chats.data throws an error which is not caught by the Error boundary. What is the possible issue here?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, `ErrorBoundary` catches an error, I suppose you think it's not working because every time an error occurs you see React's overlay.

There is no harm in having both the development error overlay and your error boundary. To view your error boundary you can close the overlay by clicking on the X in the top right corner.